# Mysterious IOException while reading a file

Tags: c#, copy, ioexception

I have this function :

```
    private static bool copyFile(string file)
    {
        string contents;
        try
        {
            contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
            File.WriteAllText(_destFile , contents);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Fairly simple, copies a file by reading the original first and then writing to my destination folder. This works the first time but the second time I call this function an exception occurs at `contents = File.ReadAllText(file);` that It is used by another process.

[image: IOException]

After this Message Box I click OK and look at my destination folder, the file is copied ( content is the same as the original ). I am certain that the file is copied because when I change content of the original file It is the same as the copied one, even though the IOException occured.

So `File.WriteAllText(_destFile , contents);` line is being run even after that IOException occured and copyFile function returns true. **How is it possible?**

My program works fine nothing is wrong. I am just curious why is it ignoring the exception and carrying on.

Comment: Exception is at `File.WriteAllText(_destFile , contents);`??

Comment: Exception is at `contents = File.ReadAllText(file);` line.

Comment: probably you need to close file, after you have read and written files in this method

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and **then closes the file**. Same with ReadAllText

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri Also I don't think you've read my Question completely because I am saying that WriteAllText line is still being run even after the exception occurred and returns true. And my expectation is that It should return false.

Comment: i read the whole question, along with the link that you have referred to me, that is why i stopped commenting, because i never have experienced the same situation, though i am agreeing with Thorarin's answer.

Comment: Any reason not to use the built-in File.Copy method?

Comment: @ShellShock I used it at first but It was failing because the file is used by another process. So I tried reading it and writing to a new location and It worked, bringing me to this 'mysterious problem'.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason why you're seeing this behavior is because you are performining the copy multiple times. One of them is most certainly failing. There is no way it can produce that exception and still write the file normally, given the code you've posted.

The other process the exception is talking about could very well be your own application.

Try putting a breakpoint at the start of the method and see if it's really only triggered when you expect it to. Also set a breakpoint on `return true;` to see if it sometimes succeeds.

Comment: I would gladly like it to be so simple by putting a breakpoint, unfortunately this exception is occurring on another computer and not mine which is very interesting.

Comment: @l0oky Log files are your friend :)

Comment: The thing is that copyFile is not failing It copies my file perfectly each time I call it but with an exception message, thats all!

Comment: That's simply not possible.

Comment: Say that to my eyes, :). I agree with you, that's why I called it a mysterious problem. There is probably something else in my code that's causing this exception.. I have to look into this further.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks OK to me (although you may not be aware of the in-built [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. I suspect the file is being locked by Internet Explorer or your anti-virus software (or something similar), particularly as you are creating the file in the Temporary Internet Files folder. This is a special Windows folder and you should not be creating your own files within it.

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find out which process is locking your file--Ctrl+F, then enter the file name.